# How to install gcc 7.4 on Catalina

Tags: gcc, homebrew, macos-catalina

How can I install gcc version 7.4 on Catalina Mac OS?

On Homebrew, if I punch in the command `brew install gcc@7` in the Terminal, I get gcc version 7.5 since that is the latest stable version for gcc@7.

Despite this, is there a way to install gcc 7.4 on Catalina via Homebrew or by some other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Just needed to type the following commands into the Terminal:

1. `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core`
2. `git fetch --unshallow`
3. `brew log gcc@7`
4. Find commit ID with the description `gcc 7.4.0` (In my case, that ID was `e04b6ba4ae1619f5a51259bb53b254a85c62392c`).
5. `git checkout e04b6ba4ae1619f5a51259bb53b254a85c62392c -- Formula/gcc@7.rb`
6. `brew install --build-bottle gcc@7`
7. `brew bottle gcc@7`
8. `git checkout -- Formula/gcc@7.rb`